# How can I clear S3 bucket before travis deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, travis-ci

This is my `.travis.yml`:

```
deploy:
  provider: s3
  access_key_id: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY
  secret_access_key: $AWS_SECRET_KEY
  bucket: domain.com
  skip_cleanup: true
  acl: public_read
  region: ap-northeast-1
  endpoint: domain.com.s3-website-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
  detect_encoding: true
  on:
    branch: master
```

But it is only upload files to bucket, not sync.
How can I sync or clear S3 bucket files?

Comment: Yeah I'm interested in this. Any progress since  June 2015? :D

Answer (score 4):

The update helped me find a solution. Thanks! It's cleaner than the answer proposed by hussfelt.

## Using awscli

Since using the listed command required some research I'll explain how I had to change my `.travis.yml` for any others who find this post.

```
before_deploy: pip install --user awscli
```

First install `awscli` to enable syncing with your S3 bucket. To run on Travis' container-based architecture we can't use `sudo`, so install to the home directory with `--user`.  On Linux, which is the default OS on Travis, binaries installed with this option is located in `~/.local/bin/`-

```
deploy:
  provider: script
```

Next, use the `script` provider to run a custom command as the deployment method.

```
  script: ~/.local/bin/aws s3 sync dist s3://example.com --region=eu-central-1 --delete
```

This line is were your files are uploaded. The `aws s3 sync` is used to sync files between a local machine and buckets. The full documentation is available [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html).

In my example `dist` is the build folder we want to upload to S3. Your build system might call it `build` or something else. "example.com" is the name of your bucket. The region argument is required to uniquely identify your bucket.

The really interesting bit in this command is the `--delete` switch which  is the solution to our problem. When set, `aws` will delete any files found in your bucket but not in your build directory.

```
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    branch: master
```

`skip_cleanup` should be set or none of your files will be uploaded. Personally I like to have Travis deploy only commits to `master`, but any configuration is possible here. See [the docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment#Conditional-Releases-with-on%3A) for more info.

## Environment

We need to give `aws` our AWS credentials to authorise any interaction. The environment variables used by `aws` are `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. hussfelt writes how to provide these in their answer. The process is also described in the Travis documentation: [encryption](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/) and [AWS specifics](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/s3).

## Full solution

```
# Deploy using awscli to enable pruning of removed files
before_deploy: pip install --user awscli
deploy:
  provider: script
  script: ~/.local/bin/aws s3 sync dist s3://example.com --region=eu-central-1 --delete      
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    branch: master
```

Comment: I was running into issues with travis finding the awscli, so instead of `before_deploy: pip install --user awscli` I did `install: pip install awscli` and then `script: aws s3 syn dist.....` and it worked fine

Answer (score 2):

To solve this I installed the AWS cli from pip and executed a before-deploy script.

This is what you need in your .travis.yml:

```
before_install:
  - pip install --user awscli
  - export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin
before_deploy: bin/deploy.sh
```

You also need to secure two environment variables inside your .travis.yml which is ready by aws-cli:

```
travis encrypt AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=YOUR_KEY_HERE --add
travis encrypt AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=YOUR_SECRET_HERE --add
```

Your bin/deploy.sh should look something like the following

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Clearing bucket: s3://your-bucket/path/inside/bucket/if/you/want"
aws s3 rm s3://your-bucket/path/inside/bucket/if/you/want --recursive --region eu-central-1
```

Not that we specify the region, which seems mandatory for aws cli here.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Be careful with the above script if you have multiple deploy-targets running at the same time, this will be triggered once for every deploy-stage.

Comment: To avoid the above you could move the directive to run the deploy script to ```after_success: "bin/deploy.sh"```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys,
The scripts above helped me to build the following that worked for me

`before_script:
  - pip install awscli
  - export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin
  - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY aws s3 rm s3://$BUCKET --recursive --region=$REGION`

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//stackoverflow.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Stack Overflow way of saying thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add on everybody else's answer. Unfortunately I can't comment because I have low reputation.

## installing awscli

I am getting error on the `pip install awscli` or `pip install awscli --user` script. Here's what worked for me for installing awscli at travisCI:

```
before_deploy:
  - pip install awscli --upgrade --user
```

### adding credentials

and if anyone wants also know how to add aws credentials, I found this [good answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44850245/6689278).

1. Setup your ENV variables, `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` at travis-ci dashboard settings. Your aws s3 commands should work if these variables are setup.